# Naming Cells with Row and Column heading using vba

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I don't know much about vba but I am stuck a task that I can't do manually.

I have a table (huge one) that I need to rename the cells from the standard RC name format.

example:

```
OCT NOV DEC
Sales   B2    C2    D2
Revnue  B3    C3    D3
Total   B4    C4    D4
Row4    B5    C5    D5
Row5    B6    C6    D6
```

I want to program something to rename the cell name (Not values) to be Sales_Oct instead of B2 and to do this to a selected range and choosing the Row and Column to read the name from.

what I want is to create a Name, I know how to do this through Name manager but the problem is the name manager allows only for the "name" to be text and not a reference from other cell value. I tried recording macro and modifying but failed to do it through Activecell.name or anything like that.

any help would be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: Not quite sure of the details, but wouldn't `="Row"&row()"_Column"&Column()` work? By "name", do you mean create a named range?  Can you please clarify what you mean, perhaps show your table as it is now, and what you expect it to look like after?

Comment: The cells are already named like that, no need to do it manually. If you use `Range("A1").Value` it will return the value in range A1.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear. what I meant was lets say the row left cell is named sales and the coulmn top cell is named Oct. I want the cell name to be "sales_Oct" instead of B2

Comment: If you want to reference cells by row & column number then use `Cells(1,2)` (cell B1).

Comment: It's not possible to change the notation used for cells (other than A1 or R1C1 built-in options). If you want to create a `Name` (named range) in Excel, this is possible, using the **Name Manager** from the Formula ribbon. If this is ultimately what you want, you should record a macro while doing this assignment on one cell, and then if you have trouble modifying it to your purposes (applying to entire selected range) please revise your question.

Comment: Yes what I want is to create a Name, I know how to do this through Name manager but the problem is the name manager allows only for the "name" to be text and not a reference from other cell value. I tried recording macro and modifying but failed to do it through Activecell.name or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

edited after OP's clarifications

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("MyTable").UsedRange '<-- change "MyTable" to actual name of the worksheet with cells to be renamed
        For Each cell In .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1)
            cell.name = Intersect(.Columns(1), cell.EntireRow) & "_" & Intersect(.Rows(1), cell.EntireColumn)
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for my ignorance but I don't have a "main code" to start with.

Comment: From what I understand, this will allow me to call for the cell values by the names of the column and row headings. this is not exactly what I want. I am using this file to import to a costing software that requires the cells to be renamed from the standard to a specific name. so the target is to change the cell name not to be able to recall it in a different way.

Comment: then you're after [Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839264(v=office.15).aspx), see edited answer